# toggleClass not working properly (or maybe just a code error)

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make my div show up once the button is clicked. Here's the code

```
<div class="post-menu">
    <button class="button">
        <i class="uil uil-ellipsis-h"></i>
    </button>
    <div id="menu-lists" class="menu-lists">
        <div><a href=""><i class="uil uil-edit-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit</a></div>
        <div><a href=""><i class="uil uil-trash"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Delete</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
div.post-menu div.menu-lists {
    /* display: none; */
    position: absolute;
    width: 140px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff7f;
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    z-index: 99;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 20px;
    height: 0;
}

.activePostMenu {
    padding: 20px;
    height: 124px;
}
```

```
$("button.button").click(function(){
    $(".menu-lists").toggleClass("activePostMenu");
});
```

I can see no errors in the web console so I can't really find the problem here.
(The div is not outside the parent either since it's placed just fine before hiding it)

Comment: Parent has `position: relative` so the child with  `position: absolute` will work just fine for sure.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the element with your browser devtools?  You'll be able to see if the class it toggled on/off correctly, which is the first step.  If that is working, it is just a CSS issue.  Click on the element in devtools and look at the CSS, is everything applied as you expect?

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll just do a trial and error if it's just a CSS problem.

Comment: To add details to the provided answer:  Your issue is *[specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)*.   Specifically, `div.post-menu div.menu-lists` is more specific than `.activePostMenu` so is applied.  The accepted answer adds specificity to `.activePostMenu` so it work.  To identify this, use browser Elements (F12) - locate the #menu-lists and look in styles - in your original code (after clicking) you'll see `.activePostMenu` classes are crossed out, meaning they've been overwritten by a definition that's more specific.

Comment: I already tried becoming more specific on selectors, but it won't really work...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update CSS. Follow the below code for the solution:

```js
 $("button.button").click(function(){
    $(".menu-lists").toggleClass("activePostMenu");
});
```

```css
div.post-menu div.menu-lists {
   display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 140px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff7f;
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    z-index: 99;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 20px;
    height: 0;
}

div.post-menu div.menu-lists.activePostMenu {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 124px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-menu">
    <button class="button">
        <i class="uil uil-ellipsis-h">[Button]</i>
    </button>
    <div id="menu-lists" class="menu-lists">
        <div><a href=""><i class="uil uil-edit-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit</a></div>
        <div><a href=""><i class="uil uil-trash"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Delete</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.   See [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Hello thank you for question
Try below code, there are some better options in jQuery try out below code once

```js
$("button.button").click(function(){
        $(".menu-lists").slideUp();
        $(this).next(".menu-lists").slideToggle();
    });
```

```css
div.post-menu div.menu-lists {
       display: none; 
       position: absolute;
       width: 140px;
       right: 0;
       background-color: #ffffff7f;
       backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
       border-radius: 20px;
       margin: 10px 5px;
       z-index: 99;
       padding: 0 20px;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-menu">
    <button class="button">
        <i class="uil uil-ellipsis-h">Button1</i> 
    </button>
    <div id="menu-lists" class="menu-lists">
        <div><a href=""><i class="uil uil-edit-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit</a></div>
        <div><a href=""><i class="uil uil-trash"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Delete</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="post-menu">
    <button class="button">
        <i class="uil uil-ellipsis-h">Button2</i>
    </button>
    <div id="menu-lists" class="menu-lists">
        <div><a href=""><i class="uil uil-edit-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit</a></div>
        <div><a href=""><i class="uil uil-trash"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Delete</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you think this helps?  What does your code do that OP's does not?  Explain your answer so it is useful for future visitors of all skill levels.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers